# I have started the thread but it's calling destructor numerous times, why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am learning threads in C++. Here is the small snippet what I have done-

```
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>

struct tes {

//Constructor
tes() {
  std::cout << "Constructor\n";
}

//Destructor
virtual ~tes() {
  std::cout << "Destructor\n";
}

void operator()() {
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; ++i ) std::cout << "Hello\n";
}

};
typedef struct tes TES;
// Method

void Input() {
  TES t1;                             //Line #1
  //t1();                             //Line #2
  std::thread thr_1(t1);              //Line #3
  thr_1.join();                       //Line #4
  //thr_1.detach();                   //Line #5 
}

//main()

int main(){
   Input();                        //calling this with parameters
   //...
}
```

In above function `Input()`, if I am calling only #1 and #2, everything is running fine. Whereas, if I am trying #1, #3 , #4(or #5 ), output is pretty messed up. Destructor calls itself numerous times and I am not getting why? please help me. THANKS!!

// output

```
Constructor
Destructor
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
...
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

Comment: My bad, typedef was missing. @CraigYoung

Comment: Sir, the only problem is I typed it manually, let me check it.@CraigYoung

Comment: That's why I said to Copy+Paste ... it avoids all the manual typo mistakes. They're an unnecessary waste of everyone's time - including yours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the output I get after running your code (after fixing it ofcourse):

```
Constructor
Destructor
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Destructor
Destructor
```

The destructor is called three times:

1. From the  `t1` object you created in the function `INPUT`. [The last one]
2. From the constructor of the `thread` after it copies you callable during `bind`. [The first print]
3. When the thread itself finishes thereby calling the destructor of the copied callable. [The second last]

Comment: Thanks, for editing. May be its compiler dependent. I am using VS 2013 and it;s calling destructor 5 times.

Comment: How and why ?Thanks!

Comment: Yes, surely its compiler dependent and mostly depends on how the `bind` is implemented and ALSO depends on the optimization settings. You might see less number of destructor calls if you raise the optimization level if not already done.

Comment: "How and why ? " Thats what I wrote in the answer. What exactly are you expecting ?

Comment: you explained me why it called 3 times but I am trying to get why 5 times.

Comment: Got it `std::ref()` is the solution. But I still did not get why and where 5 copies. Thanks!!

Comment: "you explained me why it called 3 times but I am trying to get why 5 times" I want you to read my earlier comment again. Also, did you set the optimization flag ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128225/discussion-between-devesh-pratap-singh-and-arunmu).